# JQuery Mobile - blue button on release

Tags: jquery-mobile

When releasing a button in JQuery Mobile it will turn blue for just a short duration while the action is called. It can even be seen on JQuery Mobile own website.

My question is, how do i get rid of the button getting blue?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` attribute in your CSS.

Comment: This only works on Iphone, how can i make it work on all browsers?

Comment: I don't know that all browsers will have a way to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but an `<a>` element without the href attribute has no blue border.

```
<a data-role="button">Button</a>
```

Then just use the click event to specify the behaviour ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/R7AEL/)).